# Using javascript in the Infowindow to change the Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have an img inside a Google Maps infowindow html, and `onclick`, I want the Marker icon of that pin to change.

Here's where I am:

The HTML within the infowindow:

`<img id="1" onclick="changePin(this);" src="image.png">`

Then the function:

`function changePin(venue) {

    if (venue.id == '1'){
        google.maps.Marker[0].setIcon('images/pin1.png');
        venue.id = '2';
    } else {
        google.maps.Marker[0].setIcon('images/pin2.png');
        venue.id = '1';
    }

}`

It's the `google.maps.Marker[0].setIcon('images/image2.png');` statement that I'm struggling with, I'm guessing I need to give each marker a name/ID/array position to address it.

Comment: `shout for more details if necessary` :O... I'm shouting for some code to see that you have tried.

Comment: please edit the question to add the additional information.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the marker incorrectly.  My suggestion would be to make an array of markers, then put code in the infowindow to change the icon.

Here is an example that should help (changes the icon on mouseover and from the side bar):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_hoverchange.html